# Within a view, how do I return the MEDIA_URL for Imagefield queryset?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Assume I have the following model:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('Product image', null=True,blank=True)
    view = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=VIEW_TYPES, default='FR', null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.view + "-" + self.image.url
```

I have the following queryset:

`allProductImages = ProductImage.objects.all()`

**How do I extract the MEDIA_URL + path + filename for all objects (e.g. /media/image.jpg)**

here's what I have already tried (follows on from previous queryset statement):
`urlValues = allImages.values('image')`

`<QuerySet [{'image': 'greenSwatch.jpg'}, {'image': 'blueSwatch.jpg'}, {'image': '3037-outer-black.jpg'}, {'image': '3037-outer-black.png'}]`

I'm trying to get the following:
`<QuerySet [{'image': '/media/path/greenSwatch.jpg'}, {'image': '/media/path/blueSwatch.jpg'}, {'image': '/media/path/3037-outer-black.jpg'}, {'image': '/media/path/3037-outer-black.png'}, {'image': '/media/path/3037-inner-blue.png'}, {'image': '/media/path/3037-outer-green.png'}, {'image': '/media/path/3037-outer-blue.png'}]>`

Also, I know there's no upload_to parameter specified, but this is optional according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#filefield) for Django 1.10

I'm running Django 1.10 + Python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p.image.url` gives you the full URL for the image, given p as a ProductImage instance. Since you have a queryset, you just need to iterate through; you shouldn't use `values` though.

```
allProductImages = ProductImage.objects.all()
image_urls = [p.image.url for p in allProductImages]
```

Answer (score 1):

image.url will give you the absolute path of the file